# Did the Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H) ignore durood shareef in his salah?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

During Salah We send durood shareef on Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H).

Now my question is, did Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H) ignore durood shareef in his salah or recite some other dua in place of it?

Comment: @Envayo This is already gone on far too deep for comments; I would strongly recommend you go to [meta] and make your arguments there, as these comments will be deleted.

Comment: What is durood shareef?

Comment: @Medi1Saif It's the Urdu term for الصلاة على النبي‎‎.

Comment: We don't know how or what exactly the Prophet himself used to say or do unless it was brought to us via narration. We have ahadith where he himself is instilling the tahsahud including the salat al-Ibrhamiya to his companions.

Answer (score 1):

This [arabic fatwa](https://islamqa.info/ar/176950) answers your question, he (PBUH) used the same (tashahhud) Muslims use, mentioned that

- Imam Malek in (Al-Mowattaa)
- Imam Al-Zarkashi
- Ibn Al-Refah (1/ 164)
- Ali al-Qari - Mirqat al-Mafatih  (3/ 452)
- Sheikh Al-Albani - (The original) Prophet's Prayer (Asl Sefat Salat Annabi) (3/ 904).